# How to bottom align a button in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

*My question is actually more complex then the title, but I couldn't come up with a better one.*

#### Initial Setup:

I use Bootstrap `v4.0.0-alpha.2` and I ripped out [this simple sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/). I'm not sure why and if it's relevant but I also set `flex: true` in my `_library-variable-overrides.scss` (I use [css-burrito](http://css-burrito.com/)) but since I only set it to try it out, I'm probably okay with turning it off. ;-)

#### What I want to do:

I would like to have a button in the sidebar that is bottom aligned. Ideally it's centered horizontally in the sidebar and has about `1em` margin to the bottom.

#### What my code looks like:

`_shell.scss` & `_sidenav.scss`:

```
#shell-wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#shell-wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;

    #shell-content-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: -250px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #shell-wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    
    #shell-wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;

        #shell-content-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }

    #shell-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
}


#sidenav-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#shell-wrapper.toggled { 
    #sidenav-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
}

#shell-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

/* Sidenav Styles */

.sidenav-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;

        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #999999;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }

        a:active, a:focus {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }

    >.sidenav-brand {
        height: 65px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 60px;

        a {
            color: #999999;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background: none;
        }
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #sidenav-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    
    #shell-wrapper.toggled #sidenav-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

}
```

and `index.html`:

```
<div id="shell-wrapper" class="toggled">
  <div id="sidenav-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidenav-nav">
      <li class="sidenav-brand">
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li id="logout">
        <button class="btn btn-danger-outline">Logout</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div id="shell-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!--Main Content Here-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The logout button is one in question. I just tried doing it as a `<li>` of the `sidenav-nav` but I'm not tied to this setup.

#### What I have tried so far:

*a lot!*

What came closest to what I want was adding this:

```
.sidenav-nav {
    height: 100%;
}

#logout {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
}
```

It's pretty close to my goal on a desktop browser, but hitting that *show me this on a phone* button in chrome, the logout button is just gone.

Comment: You should test this on an _actual_ mobile device using `position:absolute`, not in a browsers simulation because it seems to work fine.

Comment: I tested it via remote debugging on Chrome for Android and it *doesn't* work. The button is gone and I can overscrol the page about 80% of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't worked with css-buritto, but you could look into giving the button a class or id and passing the position:relative argument you can then set a bottom: 1em and that should position the button at the bottom. alternativly you can also look into the other position elements like fixed that could also do the trick

like you mentioned a the end

```
#logout {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1em;
}
```

Comment: css-burrito is just a way to organize your scss. I just mentioned it because I mentioned that library overrides filename.